# Android: When scanning for Wi-Fi networks using 'wifiManager.scanResults', I am not always able to get a complete list of devices sometimes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am attempting to retrieve a list of all Wi-Fi devices in my Android app using 'wifiManager.scanResults'. However, sometimes the scan results only display a few devices instead of all. I have already added all necessary permissions in the manifest file and followed the recommended best practices outlined in official documentation for Wi-Fi scanning. Despite this, some devices do not appear in the app's scan results, even though they appear in the Wi-Fi list on my phone.

I am posting this qestion again. Bcz didn't got any ans in my previous qestions.

I have referred to the official documentation below: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan